# How to collect data fabric to determinate Monthly Active Users (MAU)?

Tags: ios, google-fabric, retention

How can I collect data fabric to determinate Monthly Active Users (MAU)?

For example, Google Analytics collects data through a script, in this case -> iOS app, how to work fabric to collect same data about active user (MAU)?

I have a different data from Itunes Connect, therefore I don't trust in fabric.

Itunes connect is ok? fabric is ok?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is not very clear. Monthly Active Users are already displayed on Fabric's dashboard. Do you want to download this data or change how this data is computed?

Comment: Yes, how this data is computed for determinate MAU in fabric.

Answer (score 1):

Monthly active users is the number of unique app installations across all devices that were active over the trailing 30-day period. Note: Foreground activity must happen for a device to be active. Check out https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/answers-metrics.html#monthly-active-users for all the metric details.